# How do you find the power set within a power set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I'm trying to find P(P(A)), where A = {0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 9}. Any ideas?

Comment: There are no special tricks here. Just find the power set, $P(A)$. Then compute $P(P(A))$. I'd recommend using WolframAlpha to help shorten the calculation.

Comment: An element of ${\cal P}({\cal P}(A))$ is a set of subsets of $A$. For example, $\{1,2\}, \{4\}, \{2,4\}\in {\cal P}(A)$ and $\{\{1,2\},\{4\}, \{2,4\}\}\in {\cal P}({\cal P}(A))$. The cardinality of ${\cal P}({\cal P}(A))$ is $2^{2^6}=2^{64}$ so I don't recommend attempting to list all of the elements of this set ... Rather, try the smaller set $A=\{0,1\}$ if you wish to test your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly as said in the comments - there are no clever tricks here, you could try to compute $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$ manually. However, this is inadvisable, because for a set of cardinality $n$, the power set has cardinality $2^n$. That is to say, $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$ will have $2^{64}$ elements, which is a very big number (though most numbers are bigger). So don't waste your time.

However, if you're doing this with some purpose in mind - such as attempting to find whether a certain element is in this set - then we can be of more help, because such problems are more easily solvable.

Surely your question is a stepping stone in a larger problem?